# PHP shell_exec seems to be only running half the command

Tags: php, shell, ssl-certificate, shell-exec, lets-encrypt

I am coding a control panel for a server of mine and I am using shell_exec to run a command which uses the letsencrypt api to create a certificate.

I got the shell command from https://zerossl.com/usage.html. (I set up everything as per instruction by them and it does run correctly when executed directly in the shell by hand. N.B. it doesn't require user input at all)

Here is the shell_exec line

```
shell_exec("le.pl --key '$uname'.key --csr '$domain'.csr --csr-key '$domain'.key --crt '$domain'.crt --domains \"www.'$domain','$domain'\" --path /home/'$uname'/web/'$domain'/public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge --generate-missing --unlink --live");
```

The variables $uname and $domain are grabbed from a database and can be successfully echoed. In this case they are admin and plenixdev.tk respectively.

The current working directory (set by chdir() ) is /tmp/$uname and I have ensured that the /webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/ folder is actually created to prevent the script from tripping up there.

I first create the necessary keys in the script by running:

```
shell_exec("openssl genrsa -out '$uname'.key 4096");
```

and

```
shell_exec("openssl genrsa -out '$domain'.key 4096");
```

The shell_exec that I mentioned at the start the takes those keys and the variables and is meant to create a $domain.csr file (which it does) and a certificate file.

However, it only manages to create the .csr file (even though all the needed files are in the same folder) and somehow stops executing or invisibly erroring before it can create the certificates. When I then run the command by hand in the same folder with the .csr etc, it all runs completely fine.

And I can't seem to able to figure out what is going wrong, or dump the output on the page to be able to see any errors.

Comment: Why do you have quotes around all the php variables? That isn't in the original command. Try echo'ing the command to the screen and see that it looks right. You will see that the command will (and shouldn't) look like `... --key 'test.com'.key ...`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thank you. Really didn't this something as small as this would cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @JonathanKuhn's advice, I removed the quotes inside the shell_exec around the variables and it worked. Posting this answer so that others who go here can see it